# Siddhi 4.0 check if event doesn't arrived

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I'am using Stream Processor for receiveing events and I need to know, that there is any way, how to check that some event arrived within specified time in window? Let's say we want to check, that event arrived every 5 minutes. If it's not, we need to publish alert. Have Siddhi 4.0 any function for this purpose? My idea was counting same events in time window and then equal this count, but don't know, if it's the best way how to deal this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using logical patterns.[1](https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/documentation/siddhi-4.0/#logical-patterns)